# Regularity of the boundary of the graph of an set-valued map

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, multivalued-functions

I'm very new to the topic. I was wondering the following: with $X\subset\mathbb R^n$ a compact subset, $n\in\mathbb N^+$ and $Y=\mathbb R^m$, $m\in\mathbb N^+$  consider a set-valued map $F: X\to 2^Y$. Assume that his graph is compact, is there anything I can say about the regularity of the boundary of $\operatorname{graph}(F)$? Do you have any sharp reference to this that are accessible to a non-mathematician?

Comment: What topology are we assigning to the powerset $2^Y$ of $Y$?

Comment: Uhm, I would say the discrete one. Or If more convenient I would consider the topology induced by the Hausdorff distance, maybe with the appropriate restrictions. I'm really not in the field so I'm still not familiar with all of this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen such a construction before. As long as the topology on $2^Y$ is Hausdorff, then following argument works.

Assuming that the topology on $2^Y$ is Hausdorff, then $X\times 2^Y$ is Hausdorff. As a compact subset of $X\times 2^Y$, we know that the graph of $F$, denoted by $\Gamma(F)$, is closed. Therefore it contains its boundary $\partial\Gamma(F)$. This means that $\partial\Gamma(F)$ a closed subset of a compact Hausdorff space. Hence $\partial\Gamma(F)$ is compact and Hausdorff, and consequently it is regular.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your time. Let me understand. If I talk about the topology induced by the Hausdorff metric I'm implicitely considering the set of all bounded subsets of Y (otherwise the Hausdorff distance is not finite) and I guess bounded must be in the sense for instance of the usual norm on $R^m$. Saying that graphF is compact implies (?) that F has compact values on the whole domain X. Thus is consitent with the considered topology on 2^Y. Right?

Comment: We cannot use the Hausdorff distance to define a metric on $2^Y$. We must restrict to only the nonempty compact subsets of $Y$. I'm not sure if your second point is true or not - in may be with the use of the fact that $X$ is compact. I didn't use that hypothesis at all in the above argument.